# Find neighboring PINs on a numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, beginner, time-limit-exceeded, interview-questions

I am new to coding and to apply for an internship I need to solve several tasks. This is one of them. I wrote working code, but the program says it takes too long to complete. Help me speed up my code please.

**Requirements:**

- Time limit - 1s
- Memory Limit - 64mb
- Input- standard input
- Output- standard output

**There is a task:**

> Hi, your colleague forgot the pin code from the door to the office.
>   The keyboard is:
>
> ```
>         ┌───┬───┬───┐
>         │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
>         ├───┼───┼───┤
>         │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │
>         ├───┼───┼───┤
>         │ 7 │ 8 │ 9 │
>         └───┼───┼───┘
>             │ 0 │
>             └───┘
> ```
>
> A colleague recalls that it seems that the pin code was 1357, but
>   perhaps each digit should be shifted horizontally or vertically, but
>   not diagonally.
>
> For example, instead of 1 it can be 2 or 4, and instead of 5 it can be
>   2, 4, 6 or 8.
>
> Help a colleague get into the office.
>
> Input:
>   A string with a pin code. The length of the string is from
>   1 to 8 digits, for example, 1357.
>
> Output:
>   The source pin code and possible pin codes with regard to
>   shifts, sorted and separated by a comma.
>
> Do not forget that the pin codes must be strings, as they can begin
>   with 0, and must be sorted like strings.
>
> Examples
>
> Input: 11
>   Output: 11,12,14,21,22,24,41,42,44
>
> Input: 8
>   Output: 0.5,7,8,9
>
> Input: 46
>   Output: 13,15,16,19,43,45,46,49,53,55,56,59,73,75,76,79

**Formalization:**

```
var readline = require("readline");
           var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
           rl.on("line", function(line) {
             console.log("0,5,7,8,9")
             rl.close();
           }).on("close",function(){
             process.exit(0);
           });
```

**MY code**

````
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin,
 output: process.stdout
});

function drawMatrix(InArray) {
   let matrix= [];
   for (let z = 0; z < InArray.length; z++) {
       switch (InArray[z]) {
           case '1':
               row = [1, 2, 4];
               break;
           case '2':
               row = [1, 2, 3, 5];
               break;
           case '3':
               row = [2, 3, 6];
               break;
           case '4':
               row = [1, 4, 5, 7];
               break;
           case '5':
               row = [2, 4, 5, 6, 8];
               break;
           case '6':
               row = [3, 5, 6, 9];
               break;
           case '7':
               row = [4, 7, 8];
               break;
           case '8':
               row = [0, 5, 7, 8, 9];
               break;
           case '9':
               row = [6, 8, 9];
               break;
           case '0':
               row = [0, 8];
               break;
       };
      // console.log(row);
       matrix.push(row);
   };
  //console.log(matrix);
  return matrix;
};

function keyVars(matrix) {
   let positions = [];
   let someVar = [];
   let allVars = [];
   let totalCount = matrix.length;

   for (let  i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {  
       positions[i] = 0;
   };

   let next = totalCount - 1;

   while (next >= 0) {
       for (let i=0; i < totalCount; i++) {
           someVar.push(matrix[i][positions[i]]);
       };

       next = totalCount - 1;

       let Var = someVar.join('');
       someVar = [];


       while (next >=0 && (positions[next] + 1) >= matrix[next].length) {
       next--;
       };

       positions[next]++;

       for (let i = next + 1; i < totalCount; i++) {
           positions[i] = 0;
       };

       allVars.push(Var);
   };

   let allVarsStr = allVars.join();
   return allVarsStr;
};

rl.on('line', (input) => {
   console.log(`Входные данные: ${input}`);
   console.log(`Выходные данные: ${keyVars(drawMatrix(input))}`);
   rl.close();
 }).on("close",function(){
   process.exit(0);
 });

```
````

Comment: You use heayvy array functions. Which are internally a time eater. Why not simply use a string with 10 chars ? either something like  "0123456789" or "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" last ones can be fast transformed into array by using the split function.

Comment: "0123456789" can be indexed like an array without any transformation at all.  `"0123456789"[9] === "9"`

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify this quite a bit.  At a high level, note that all you are doing is:

1. Converting each digit of the input to an array of possible neighbors.
2. Now you have an array of neighbor arrays.
3. The answer is simply the cartesian cross product of those neighbor arrays.
4. Sort them.
5. Turn the into back into strings.

The cartesian cross-product is a simple utility method.

The neighbor possibilities are more compactly expressed as a JS object than by a switch statement, and this representation also makes it easy to map over them.

Putting it all together we get:

```
function xprod(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((m, x) => m.flatMap(
    results => x.map(elm => results.concat([elm]))
  ), [ [] ])
}

function possibleCodes(code) {
  const neighbors = {
    '1': [1, 2, 4],
    '2': [1, 2, 3, 5],
    '3': [2, 3, 6],
    '4': [1, 4, 5, 7],
    '5': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8],
    '6': [3, 5, 6, 9],
    '7': [4, 7, 8],
    '8': [0, 5, 7, 8, 9],
    '9': [6, 8, 9],
    '0': [0, 8],
  }
  const possibilitiesByDigit = code.split('').map(x => neighbors[x])
  return xprod(...possibilitiesByDigit).map(x => x.join('')).sort()
}
```